# Modifying a class so it can be used as a key in HashMap

Tags: java

```
class Employee

{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int empid;

    public Employee(String name, int age, int empid) 
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.empid = empid;
    }
}
```

How to modify above class so it can be used as a key  in HashMap

Comment: Override `Object.hashCode()` and `Object.equals(Object)`.

Comment: `super();` ? what are you extending ?

Comment: @alfasin `Object` (looks like the constructor was automatically created and the `super()` call was auto-inserted)

Comment: Why is this being voted close for off topic? I can understand too localized or dup.

Answer (score 4):

There are basically three things need to be done for a class that you want to use as a key in a hashmap. First make the class immutable, second override the hashCode method, third override the equals method.

**To make the class immutable. Here are few of the rules for immutability:**

- Make the class final
- make all members final, set them explicitly, in a static block, or in the constructor
- Make all members private
- No Methods that modify state

**Learn more about creating immutable classes from this tutorial:**

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-create-immutable-class-object-java-example-tutorial.html

**To learn about overriding the hashCode and equals method, follow this:**

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html

Comment: Although a good idea, the key being immutable is not a requirement

Answer (score 0):

It can be used in a hashmap already. *All* Java objects have a `hashCode` and `equals` method, which are what's necessary for a hashmap to work.

```
Map<Employee, Whatever> theMap = new HashMap<Employee, Whatever>();
```

Comment: Yes, but garbage in, garbage out. If you screw around with your instantiated objects such that having them in a map doesn't make sense, you can't expect to get amazing results.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a class to be used as an effective hash map key, the class should override both `equals` and `hashCode`.  The `hashCode` variable returns an int that is used to figure out the low-level lookup index of this particular object.

Making the class immutable is also a good idea too as if hashCode changes mid-program your key is now useless.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have top do anything. All classes extend the Object class. And since the methods `hashcode()` and `equals()` are defined in the Object class, any class can be used as a key.

However, you should override both of these methods if you really indend on using your class as a HashMap key.

If you are using Eclipse as your IDE, it can generate both of these functions for you.
Just do Richt-Click anywhere in your source **->** Source **->**  Generate Hashcode() and equals().

Answer (score 0):

Sufficient Conditions for making a Custom Class as key in Your HashMap.

```
   1. Override equals and Hashcode - good practice.
      Read Item 8 and Item 9 from Effective Java (must Read) for 
      the general contract among them.
   2. Try to make your Class Immutable. Atleast 
      those fields should be final/immutable on which your hashcode 
      and equals depend. So that you hashcode/equals in dosen't fail later
      in your program
```

If you think you want to check equality on reference only(not recommended) then use IdentityHashMap.